# jquery mobile dropdown not working in android 2.2.1 and above

Tags: android, cordova

i am very new for phone-gap. i just try one android phone-gap application, in this application i am using drop down list, its working fine in android 2.2 devices. but its not working in android2.2.1 and above version of android devices. i searched about this problem, finally find "data-native-menu="false"" if i using this one mean its working but i want native menu style only, if i use data-native-menu="false" mean, in android keybord next button is disable.

If i click text box mean that keyboard is coming, then i click previous or next mean that time drop down is coming. But if i click drop down directly, that time drop down is coming coming.

how to solve this problem?. Please anyone can help me?

Comment: i solve this problem in my application. i am using jqm-docs.css, in this css default ui-page style is

.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

here i changed like,

.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

now my drop down is working fine.